# Scrape a website using font or colors in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I need to scrape prices off a website and I run into a problem where certain prices are crossed out and a new price is shown in red/bold letters and the html code is different for that code so I am getting null for my price.  So I decided to do an if statement to get the right data but the only problem is, the crossed out price has the same identifier so I get that price instead of the one in red.  So is there a way in **Scrapy**, to scrape the price I need based on the color being red or the font being bold?  If not is there another way for me to get the right price?

[image: Partial HTML code for price, need the second price, 13.49]

```
 for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):

            # Initialize saved_name to the extracted card name
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first() or saved_name
            # Now call item and set equal to saved_name and strip leading '\n' from output
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            # Check to see if output is null, in the case that there are two different conditions for one card
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                # If not null than store value in saved_name
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            # If null then set null value to previous card name since if there is a null value you should have the same card name twice
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["Stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").extract_first()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").extract_first()
            if item["Price"] == None:
                item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span::text").get()

            # Return values
            yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your expression:

```
if item["Price"] == None:
    item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span[style*='color:red']::text").get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter it using style attribute

```
response.css('span[style^="color:red;"]::text').get()
```